# How to pass date picker from one page to another

Tags: php

how can i pass a date picker from one page to another page and according to that how can I fetch data from database using PHP to display it?

**UPDATE**

Firstly, i just want to said that i use PDO to access the database.
Second, i dont use session method because i just want to make it simple. 
after read the comment, i thing that i need to learn about `get` and `post` method. After learn about `get` and `post` method, now i can send the data from one page to other page. i also can sent data in form that *phpmyadmin* can read.

Thanks.

Comment: There are two ways the browser client can send information to the web server.

The GET Method
The POST Method

Comment: The `SESSION` method

Comment: thanks @Arun for the answer. i already read the `GET` and `POST` method.

Comment: Sorry @SaadSuri , i dont use the session method.

Comment: can u add flag for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to submit data when going on to another page. Date picker is essentially a front-end handler for a form input. As any form element it needs to be submitted (via GET or POST). On you receiving script (form `action=`). You can either, store it to DB as any other variable value as it will be available in `$_GET` or `$_POST` as a text variable, or just use that value to populate your date picker on the next page if you do not need to store it on this step.

If you need any additional help with any of the steps: form submission, DB queries, populating date pickers, please show us your attempts to achieve the result and we will be able to guide you towards the right direction.

Comment: nice, thanks for the help. Now i can pass the data to next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get datepicker value depends your methods post and get and your input name.
for example if your code is

```
<form method="post" action="resp.php">
<input class="timepicker logs-datepicker" name="from_date" value="" type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

in resp.php page

```
$time = $_POST['from_date'];
```

and for change to timestamp

```
$time = strtotime($time,' 00:00:00');
```